# Django self.client.post does not send data to view with decorator

Tags: python, django, post, python-unittest, django-unittest

I have a simple test case which checks that `POST` request with valid data returns an HTML response with 200 status code:

```
class PostRequestTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_valid_post_request(self):
        response = self.client.post('/foo/', data={'text': 'bar'})
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Here is the view `foo` which is triggered for that request:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# decorator to trace enter and exit events
enter_exit_tracer = enter_exit_Tracer(logger)

@enter_exit_tracer
def foo(request):  
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #
        print('request.POST:', request.POST)
        # 
        # some stuff
```

where `@enter_exit_tracer` is a decorator to trace entering/exiting a function:

```
def enter_exit_Tracer(logger):
    def middle(f): 
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            session_string = args[-1] if 'session_key' in args[-1] else '[]'
            logger.debug('%s Enter %s.', session_string, f.__name__)
            result = f(*args, **kwargs)
            logger.debug('%s Exit %s.',  session_string, f.__name__)
            return result
        return inner
    return middle
```

It turns out that when I add this decorator to `foo` function, then the `POST` data sent via `self.client.post` are actually not passed to `foo`. They are missing in the test request - so my test fails:

```
DEBUG: [] Enter foo.
request.POST: <QueryDict: {}>
ERROR: Invalid form
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_valid_post_request (textstat.tests.PostRequestTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Pro/myapp/tests.py", line 111, in test_valid_post_request
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
AssertionError: 400 != 200

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.018s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

We see `request.POST: <QueryDict: {}>` and eventually this leads to `ERROR: Invalid form`.

At the same time when I do the similar `POST` request but via a web browser everything works fine - the form gets populated with data, the web page is rendered ok and `@enter_exit_tracer` does its logging as expected.

If I comment out `@enter_exit_tracer` decorator then everything works also ok and the test is passed:

```
request.POST: <QueryDict: {'text': ['bar']}>
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.007s

OK
```

The questions:

- why the `request.POST` data are not passed to the view with the decorator in case of `self.client.post` request?
- if anything wrong with the decorator - why then the web request works ok?
- is it possible to keep the decorator and make`self.client.post` pass the data to the view?

Comment: Does the logging get called with the client?

Comment: Yes, the logger gets called with the client as it is initialized in the view decorator. For example, we see that in `self.client.post` there is `DEBUG: Enter foo.` in output log.

Comment: Actually I oversimplified the code in the question by removing `session_string = args[-1] if 'session_key' in args[-1] else '[]'` from the posted code of the decorator. I believed that this line of the code could not be the cause of the pb. And I was wrong - this line was the source of the pb. More details in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the decorator has a `TypeError` error in this line:

```
session_string = args[-1] if 'session_key' in args[-1] else '[]'
```

So when `args[-1]` is not `str` then this should not work. Fixing it with `str(args[-1])` resolves the whole issue with missing `POST` data.

It is weird though that `self.client.post` does not raise any `TypeError` and `session_string` was somehow calculated. Instead of this `POST` data were not sent to the view without any errors or hint warnings. `POST` data were just disappeared. At the same time the same code worked ok when `POST` request was sent from web browser, so the error remained unnoticed.